# Оптимизировать WhereHas запрос на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

у меня есть довольно большой запрос в базу, который фильтрует значения и возвращает builder экземпляр.
Модель accommodation имеет отношение belongsToMany к модели Category.

```
 ->when($categoryIds = Arr::get($args, 'categoryIds'), function ($query) use ($categoryIds) { 
            $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categoryIds) {
                $q->whereIn('categories.id', $categoryIds);
            }, '=', count($categoryIds));
```

В этом месте мне нужно найти accommodations, которые имеют все айдишники категорий, полученные из запроса. Раньше код работал быстро, но именно этот кусок заставляет локальный сервер падать, а на сервере запрос выполняется неприлично долго. Возможно, есть какой-то более оптимальный способ получить accommodations

Comment: давайте чтобы и мы и вы понимали о чем речь на диалекте БД вы напишите не php код, а во что он превращается при отправке в БД